# Как лучше всего отнять дату от даты и получить количество дней?

Tags: дата, php

Как лучше всего отнять дату от даты и получить количество дней?
Дата формата Y-m-d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$dateA = '1970-10-13';
$dateB = '2016-10-12';

$dateA = new DateTime($dateA);
$dateB = new DateTime($dateB);

$diff = $dateA->diff($dateB, true); // true - аналог модуля числа, заставит diff вернуть положительный интервал

// для версий 5.4+
$diff->days; // необходимое число
// для более ранних версий
$days = (int) $diff->format('%a');
```

Answer (score 0):

Учись гуглить, [вот ответ на первой позиции в гугле.](http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-beginners/thread659724.html)

Comment: Вы серьезно считаете, что этим можно пользоваться?

Answer (score 0):

Преобразовать даты в целое число, а после отнять первое число от второго, а дальше уже понятно. )